# Cross compiling kernel module throwing error "/bin/sh: 1: scripts/mod/modpost: not found"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, yocto, kernel-module

I am cross compiling kernel module using my own generated toolchain of yocto kirkston source but it's throwing error that "/bin/sh: 1: scripts/mod/modpost: not found". I could see `modpost.c` & `modpost.h` files in toolchain but couldn't find shell script for the same. Find the same source & header file in `linux-libc-headers` also but script is missing. Attaching the detailed logs below, any suggestion on this will be really helpful.

```
make ARCH=arm64 -I/opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa72-poky-linux/usr/include/asm -C /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa72-poky-linux/lib/modules/5.15.72-yocto-standard/build M=/home/agl/Automotive/ADAS_Infotainment/project/Application/Xen modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa72-poky-linux/lib/modules/5.15.72-yocto-standard/build'
arch/arm64/Makefile:36: Detected assembler with broken .inst; disassembly will be unreliable
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
  You are using:           aarch64-poky-linux-gcc (GCC) 11.3.0
  MODPOST /home/agl/Automotive/ADAS_Infotainment/project/Application/Xen/Module.symvers
/bin/sh: 1: scripts/mod/modpost: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:133: /home/agl/Automotive/ADAS_Infotainment/project/Application/Xen/Module.symvers] Error 127
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1813: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa72-poky-linux/lib/modules/5.15.72-yocto-standard/build'
make: *** [Makefile:5: all] Error 2
```

I have included kernel-modules, kernel-devsrc & kernel-dev in local.conf file.
Expecting that modpost should be generated.

Comment: What are you doing? (aka: which `make` command you gave). You have the `modpost.c`, and that is the source of the tool. For some reason it was not compiled. I suspect you forgot a necessary step to compile the kernel (but you didn't write anything about what you were doing). (I think you should do the right steps instead of compiling such program, because other parts may not be setup correctly)

Comment: I have build xen-guest-image-minimal on kirkston yocto source & ported it also as a guest domain on raspberrypi4. But somehow one of it's module is not working 
as expected. So i have added debugging logs to it & trying to compile the source to generate .ko file. I have populate toolchain for the same image & install it in
 ubuntu 20.04, Setting up cross compile environment & compiling it. But it could not find modpost in scripts, below is the make file used to compile kernel module.

Comment: obj-m += mydevicefront.o
INC=-I/opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa72-poky-linux/usr/include/asm

all:
make ARCH=arm64 $(INC) -C /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa72-poky-linux/lib/modules/5.15.72-yocto-standard/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
make ARCH=arm64 -C /opt/poky/4.0.5/sysroots/cortexa72-poky-linux/lib/modules/5.15.72-yocto-standard/build M=$(PWD) clean

Comment: Please edit the question (to add further information), and you still do not write what did you do. Write down all the `make` commands you used.

Comment: I believe i have included everything, building steps for xen-guest-image-minimal is something common. I used "bitbake -k xen-guest-image-minimal" for building image. Modified kernel configuration with command "bitbake -c menuconfig linux-yocto" & "bitbake -k linux-yocto". Used "make" command to build kernal module source for the make file shared earlier, didn't use any arguments with make command.

Comment: If I read correctly the kernel sources, you should `make modules_prepare` before building modules. I have no idea of bitbake/yocto. Maybe they forgot to run it, or maybe you skipped the preparation step